# Exerting force upon oneself in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, space

In space, there is no friction or forces of resistance of any kind, so I would assume that if two people were in space and one of them punched or pushed the other, the person upon which the force was exerted would start moving slowly and would not stop. My question, however, is what would happen if this person then hit themselves with an equal amount of force as the other person initially hit them with, and in the opposite direction? Would it slow them down?

Comment: Due to Newton's (weak) law of action and reaction, a point mass cannot exert a force on itself. If you instead considered some other force (say, due to a chemical reaction), then if that force were in the opposite direction of the initial push, then the person's speed would indeed decrease.

Comment: A good answer to this question could include a free body diagram illustrating why it's not possible for a single object to exert a force on itself.

Comment: You could always cut off the less useful hand and chuck it away to provide momentum to the remaining body (ejecting mass), but I doubt that's a desirable option to take.

Comment: This is why the NASA et al "reactionless drive" is so 'exciting'. IF it works it will allow energy to be converted to reaction and would eg allow geostationary satellites to station-keep without mission length being reaction fuel mass limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to hit yourself (to be specific, let's say you're using your hand to hit your chest) then your hand would indeed produce a force on your chest, but your chest would also produce a force on your hand that is equal in strength and opposite in direction (Newton's Third Law).  The combined effect of these two forces (when looking at your body as a whole instead of the individual body parts) cancel out, leaving you with no acceleration overall.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your orientation by moving your limbs on a rotational manner, like the reaction wheels used on satellites. Then when well positioned if able to eject something  that would work for 
speeding you down. 
[image: reaction wheel]